# snowflake: create or replace table when only a condition is met

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement to create or replace a table only if certain variable value is 1

```
SET variable = (select statement) -- $variable will be 1 or 0 depending on value returned from select statment

create or replace table2 as select * from table1 (only if $variable =1)
```

Is there any way to do it? If the variable value is 0, the create statement should be skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/) block:

```
-- CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT 1 AS col;

SET variable = (SELECT 1);

BEGIN
   IF ($variable = 1) THEN 
      create or replace table table2 as select * from table1;
   END IF;
END;
```

---

Variable could be defined also at Snowflake Scripting block level:

```
DECLARE
   variable INTEGER := (SELECT 1);
BEGIN
   IF (:variable = 1) THEN 
      create or replace table table2 as select * from table1;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: If you run this from the Snowflake classic web interface or the SnowSQL client, these blocks must be called like this: `execute immediate $$ <sql_script_block> $$`