# snowflake: create a table using query 1 when a condition is met otherwise create a table using query 2

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a logic that I need to implement in snowflake. The logic is like this:

```
If variable_1 = 'US':

   create temp table table1 as( select * from sourcetable_1 where date < '2022-10-01' and region = variable_1 ); 
   insert into table1 as select * from sourcetable_2 where date >= '2022-10-01' and region = variable_1;

else:
   create temp table table1 as( select * from sourcetable_1 where region = variable_1);
```

What should I implement this logic in snowflake? I tried to use BEGIN END as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73250079/snowflake-create-or-replace-table-when-only-a-condition-is-met) , but it didn't work. thank you

Comment: Can you provide details of how it didn't work?  "It didn't work" helps no one help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just run the three selects with UNION ALL (to take all rows) and put the if, into each logic:

```
create temp table table1 as
    select * 
    from sourcetable_1 
    where date < '2022-10-01' 
        and region = variable_1 
        and (variable_1 = 'US') = TRUE
    
    union all
    
    select * 
    from sourcetable_2 
    where date >= '2022-10-01' 
        and region = variable_1 
        and (variable_1 = 'US') = TRUE
        
    union all
    
    select * 
    from sourcetable_1 
    where region = variable_1 
        and (variable_1 = 'US') = FALSE
```

Also `*` is super dangerous, if ether table changes shape (which tend to happen all the time)

Comment: Thank you Simeon. I might didn't explain myself well. But each time, we can only work on on variable_1. Either US or other countries as different regions will run at different time of the day. But in the above solution, we are putting all regions together which is not what I want. Do you have any other thoughts? Thank you

Comment: The primary trick is to put a clause into the each where clause thus the third branch never returns rows at the same time as the first two do. Almost like a `WHERE FALSE = TRUE`